# Prepared statements for MySQL from PHP (with mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have these tables in a MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
`idProduct` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`category` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idProduct`)
);

CREATE TABLE `sale` (
`idSale` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`highDate` date NOT NULL,
`idProduct` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
`idUser` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`idSale`)
);
```

I would like to get a table with the users in rows and products in columns, like this question:
[MySQL Pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

In [SQL Fiddle (Demo)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ff5b1/1) works fine but I need help to query it from PHP with mysqli.

Is this correct?

```
$this->dbh->query("SET @sql = NULL");
$stmt = $this->dbh->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
                          CONCAT(
                          'count(case when category = ''',
                          category,
                          ''' then 1 end) AS ',
                          replace(category, ' ', '')
                       )
                    ) INTO @sql
                FROM product;");

$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare("SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT s.idUser, ', @sql, ' FROM sale s
                            LEFT JOIN product p ON p.idProduct = s.idProduct
                            GROUP BY s.idUser');");

$stmt->execute();
```

How can I retrieve the data from the query? Execute() method returns TRUE or FALSE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did the following:

```
$query = $this->dbh->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONC...");
$result = array();
$row = $query->fetch_row();

$query = $this->dbh->query("SELECT " . $row[0] . " FROM sale s ...");
return $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this for fetching result

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    //code
}
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: Ok, thanks! The problem is: How can I know the number of columns? To use `fetch()` I need to do before `bind_result($column1, $column2,...)` but I don't know how many columns retrieves the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$stmt->fetch` or `$stmt->get_result()` to retreive results from the queried statement as follows:

[`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php)

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $name, $code);
}
```

[`get_result()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php)

```
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    foreach ($row as $r) {
        print "$r ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```